# Asp .net Linkbutton child controls dissapears on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp .net hyperlink control declared like this:

```
  <li runat="server" id="liveChatCtrl" Visible="false"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="hlnkLiveChat" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="hlnkLiveChat_Click">Live Chat Support <i class="icon icon_next_03 fr"></i><i runat="server" id="iconChat" class="icon_chat_online"></i></asp:LinkButton></li>
```

My problem is that the contents of the linkbutton disappears on postback. Any ideas why this is happening?

On load I execute the following code on the linkbutton or it's children:

```
                string absoluteURL = UtilManager.Settings.Item(Utils.BrandID, "URL:absoluteURL");
            string chatLink = "StartChat.aspx";
            if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                chatLink = "LiveChat.aspx";//~/
            //else
            //    chatLink = "SalesChat.aspx";
            string link = absoluteURL + chatLink;
            hlnkLiveChat.Attributes["onclick"] = string.Format("javascript:window.open( '{0}', 'chat', 'status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,height=505,width=420,left=30,top=30');", link);//"openPopup('" + link + "','chat'); return false;";            
            liveChatCtrl.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Where do you execute code that gives hyperlink its content?

Comment: In the page init event

Comment: Something to check, if that `LinkButton` content is wrapped in an `if( !Page.IsPostback())` it will be rendered initially and then disappear on postback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A guess...

I believe you may have the code in your `Page_Load` (or `Init`) inside an `if(!IsPostBack)`

If this is the case, move it outside of this `if` statement as you need it to run as your default `visible` for your `liveChatCtrl` is `false`

Either that or re-code a little so that your default `visible` is true and you run a check on postback to hide it if needed.